# Select box how to pick prev and next

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
echo "<form name=\"form1\" method=\"post\"  action=\"\">\n";
echo "<select name=\"roll_1\" id=\"roll_1\"size=\"3\">\n";
echo "  <option value=\"1\">1</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"2\">2</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"3\">3</option>\n"; <--- User select how to pick the prev and next value
echo "  <option value=\"4\">8</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"5\">9</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"6\">6</option>\n";
echo "</select>\n";
echo "<select name=\"roll_2\" id=\"roll_2\"size=\"3\">\n";
echo "  <option value=\"1\">1</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"2\">2</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"3\">3</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"1\">4</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"2\">7</option>\n";
echo "  <option value=\"3\">8</option>\n";
echo "</select>\n";
echo '<input type="submit" name="Send" id="Send"  class="button" value="Send">';
echo "</form>\n";

$a = $_POST['roll_1'];
$b = $_POST['roll_2'];
```

How can i pick the prev and next value after selections and store in mysql ..
if i select option 3 how to pick opition 2 and option 4

Comment: With jQuery ajax. Or, when you submit, then use the same logic as you display to get the data out. Or, send all the values of the select in a hidden field, and get from that.

Comment: Yes but how can sombady show me example...

Comment: It would be nicer without all those echoes

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden input box inside your form as below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="roll_1_next" id="roll_1_next">
<input type="hidden" name="roll_1_prev" id="roll_1_prev">
```

And add below js which will pick up the next and previous values of drop down and place in hidden box.

```
var next = jQuery('#roll_1 option:selected').next().attr('value');
var prev = jQuery('#roll_1 option:selected').prev().attr('value');
jQuery("#roll_1_next").val(next);
jQuery("#roll_1_prev").val(prev);
```

And in PHP you can get it like:

```
$next = $_POST['roll_1_next'];
$prev = $_POST['roll_1_prev'];
```